# DataContext.GetChangeSet shows updates but not inserts

Tags: winforms, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I am using Linq to SQL with stored procedures to query a simple database.  On my form I have a datagridview with some controls for some query fields.  Users type in street name/number/direction etc. then get back results in the datagrid.  The grid uses a bindingSource together with a bindingNavigator to get the results.  I can navigate, get results back as a list<> from my DAL and call the update Stored proc which works well.  However when I use the built-in commands for adding a new record, it successfully adds the record to the grid, but when I try to use GetChangeSet in the DAL on the DataContext I have 0 inserts showing.

So the DataContext is tracking my changes to existing records but not seeing any added records.  I am using a private static datacontext in DAL.  I guess the question is how do I go about adding the new record and passing that to my stored proc method??  I don't see any way to "get added record(s)" from bindingsource, or how could I use the grid to see if I need to add a new record??

Code in UI/Form that calls my DAL

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Call search query
        spSearchCardsResultBindingSource.DataSource = 
            SideSewer.QueryCards(permit:txtPermit.Text, 
            parcel: txtParcel.Text, streetNum: nullNum1,
            streetNum2: nullNum2, streetDirection: cbDirection.Text, 
            streetName: txtName.Text, streetType: cbType.Text,
            inspected: inspectedNull, includeAliases: ckbxAlias.Checked);
    }

    private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This line below actually WORKS, yet it just adds the record 
        // user currently has selected may NOT be the NEW one!!
        SideSewer.InsertData((PermitInfo)spSearchCardsResultBindingSource.Current);

        if (!SideSewer.save())
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem saving the record(s)");
    }
```

Here is the code for querying the records and doing the save.  The save works for updates but whenever I add a record in the grid it adds it to the List of PermitInfo but doesn't show up in GetChangeSet.

```
private static SideSewerDataContext _dc = new SideSewerDataContext();

public static List<PermitInfo> QueryCards(string permit = null, 
string parcel = null, int? streetNum = null, int? streetNum2 = null, 
string streetDirection = null,string streetName = null, 
string streetType = null,DateTime? inspected = null, bool? includeAliases = null)
{
    try
    {
        return dc.spSearchCards(permit, parcel, streetNum, streetNum2, 
        streetDirection, streetName, streetType, inspected, includeAliases).ToList();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message,"Error Occured!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static bool save()
    {

        ChangeSet cs = _dc.GetChangeSet();

        try
        {
            foreach (var obj in cs.Updates)
            {
                if (obj is PermitInfo)
                {
                    PermitInfo pInfo = (PermitInfo)obj;
                    _dc.spUpdatePermitInfo(pInfo.ID, pInfo.Permit, pInfo.Parcel, pInfo.StreetNumber, pInfo.StreetNumberSuffix, pInfo.StreetDirection, pInfo.StreetName, pInfo.StreetType, pInfo.Inspected, Environment.UserName.ToUpper());
                }
            }
            foreach (var obj in cs.Inserts)
            {
                if (obj is PermitInfo)
                {
                    PermitInfo pInfo = (PermitInfo)obj;
                    _dc.spInsertPermitInfo(Environment.UserName.ToUpper(), pInfo.Permit, pInfo.Parcel, pInfo.StreetNumber, pInfo.StreetNumberSuffix, pInfo.StreetDirection, pInfo.StreetName, pInfo.StreetType, pInfo.Inspected);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thank you ahead of time to anyone that looks at this and can give me some insight into what I am doing wrong or how to go about what I need to accomplish!!

Comment: Why are you doing this manually?  You can just call `.SubmitChanges()` on your `DataContext`.

Comment: I have some history/logging tables, so when anyone deletes/inserts/updates records my stored procs add a record into those tables as well, with fields like environment.username etc. I didn't see any way in the entity behavior to tie up the stored proc to inserts but use variables like environment.username, so I am calling the stored procs manually with the parameters I need.

Comment: I've noticed that if I have my DataGridView.DataSource set to my BindingSource and then the BindingSource.DataSource set to the IList returned from my DAL it doesn't work.  If I just set the DataGridView.DataSource = (IList returned from DAL) it inserts rows that I add...